# How many times must I flip a coin if I want a 50% chance that I'll flip heads twice in a row? What about 3 times in a rows, 4, etc.?

Tags: probability-theory

How many times must I flip a coin if I want a 50% chance that I'll flip heads twice in a row? What about 3 times in a rows, 4, etc.?

2 heads in a row should require 4flips to have a 50% chance to get those 2 heads in a row right? This is because with 4 flips you have 16 outcomes and 8 of those outcomes have at least 2 heads in a row.

But what about 3? Etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of two consecutive heads, you can express the general term in terms of the $n$th Fibonacci number, by varying slightly the reasoning in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1355540/301095) (I do this below). The idea is basically considering how you would build a valid sequence of tosses of length $n$ from one of length $n-1$ or length $n-2$ (and that's how Fibonacci pops up).

The probability of at least 2 successive heads after $n$ throws is $$1-\frac{F_{n+2}}{2^n},$$
and indeed, with $n=4$, we have $1-\frac{F_{4+2}}{2^4} = 1 - \frac{8}{16}=\frac12$.
The corresponding sequence is available on OEIS [here](https://oeis.org/A008466).

The reasoning for the general case of more than 2 coins generalises similarly. If you want $k$ successive heads, the probability is basically
$$1-\frac{F_{k,\,n+k}}{2^n}$$
where $F_{3,n}$ denotes the $n$th [Tribonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers), $F_{4,n}$ denotes the $n$th [Tetranacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tetranacci_numbers), etc, using the generalised Fibonacci numbers.  See the OEIS sequences for 3 and 4 coins [here](https://oeis.org/A050231) and [here](https://oeis.org/A050232).

Computationally, you can also see that this is not always possible to have probability precisely equal to $\frac12$, e.g., for $k=3$ heads, we have that the probability is $0.46$ when $n=9$, but $0.51$ when $n=10$. Similarly, when $k=4$, we have probability $0.497$ when $n=21$ and probability $0.515$ when $n=22$.

---

#### Proof of the formula for the case where $k=2$

Let $F(n)$ denote the number of sequences of the letters in $\{H,T\}$ of length $n$, having *no two successive $H$'s*. Clearly we have $F(1) = 2$ and $F(2) = 3$.

Now to build a sequence of length $n$ with no successive $H$'s, you can  start from one of length $n-1$ and add a $T$ on the end, or else start from one of length $n-2$ and add an $HT$ to the end. It follows that $$F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2),$$
and since $F(1) = 2 = F_3$ and $F(2) = 3 = F_4$, it follows that $F(n) = F_{n+2}$.

Now we are interested in sequences which *do* contain at least one pair of successive $H$'s, this is simply the remaining ones, i.e., there are $2^n - F_{n+2}$ in number. $\qquad\square$

---

#### Generalising the proof for $k\geqslant 3$

The idea is basically induction on $k$. Indeed, we can build a sequence of length $n$ with no successive heads by:

- adding a $T$ to one of length $n-1$
- adding an $HT$ to one of length $n-2$
- adding an $HHT$ to one of length $n-3$

  $\qquad\vdots$
- adding an $\underbrace{H\cdots H}_{k-1}T$ to one of length $n-k$.

It follows that

$$F(n)=F(n-1) + F(n-2) + \cdots + F(n-k),$$
and by induction, we can establish that $F(n) = F_{k,\,n+k}$ for $1\leqslant n \leqslant k$.

Thus we get that the number of sequences of length $n$ with at least $k$ successive heads somewhere is $2^n - F_{k,\,n+k}$.