# In how many ways can they be coloured such that each circle is coloured either red or green and no three successive circles are coloured red

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are $10$ congruent circles placed in a row. In how many ways can they be coloured such that each circle is coloured either red or green(but not both) and no three successive circles are coloured red.

**My Attempt**

I tried by considering cases for possible number of green and red balls but there were many cases and with increasing number of red balls things really got complicated.I am wondering whether there is an altogether a different approach

Comment: Why does it matter that they are "congruent circles"?  Aren't you just asking for the number of binary strings of length $10$ with no $000$ ?  That's a standard recursion, since every sufficiently long good string must end in one of $1,10,100$.  Or have I misunderstood the problem?

Comment: Ok. I see it now. But how to obtain this recursion. Do you mean $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$

Comment: Absolutely, yes!

Comment: This is the so called [Tribonacci recursion](http://oeis.org/A000073). Note the shift in index.   It hasn't got a terrific closed form, but the associated cubic only has one root with norm $>1$ so for large $n$ it's easy to estimate $a_n$.  Of course, for small $n$ the recursion is all you need.

Comment: I got the answer using above recursion. The required number of ways is 504

Comment: I agree with that value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability that no two consecutive heads occur?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355511/probability-that-no-two-consecutive-heads-occur)

Comment: Yes. The explanation for recursion formula is applicable here .